# Select layers for composition legend in QGIS

Tags: dictionary, expression, legend, composition, qgis

I want to choose specific layers when I'm putting the legend in a map composition. There is an option in which I can write the name of the layers separated by a | . But I have many copies of the layer with diferent simbolizations, I have organized the layers by groups.

I know that I can do it manually, but Is there any way to select the layer including the name of the group in the expression?

I wrote the name of the layers as can be seen in the image, but I don´t know how to choose a layer from an specific group by writing an expression

[image: expression]